# why header is different in query result with taos shell and jdbc in TDengine database

Tags: tdengine

with the same query, in taos shell I got result like:

```sql
taos> select last(ts, c1) from db.stb where t0 = 'shanghai'\G;
*************************** 1.row ***************************
ts: 2020-10-01 00:00:09.999
c1: NFLxdQTArXRz88eZizveRdtcPgomSEl7XottIKO0LTKJEoKgRf2FVKp2AmYFpvtLqk311k
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.006903s)
```

in JDBC, I got result like:

> [ OK ] Connection established. [ OK ] time cost: 110 ms, execute
> statement ====> select last(ts, c1) from db.stb where t0 = 'shanghai'
> last(ts): 2020-10-01 00:00:09.999       last(c1):
> NFLxdQTArXRz88eZizveRdtcPgomSEl7XottIKO0LTKJEoKgRf2FVKp2AmYFpvtLqk311k
> connection closed.

why the header is different for same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the header name can be configured with **keepColumnName** in /etc/taos/taos.cfg

```
# the last_row/first/last aggregator will not change the original column name in the result fields
keepColumnName            1
```